# Group rows by value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

How to programmatically group following data by values in column `B`?

Note, that there are random values in columns `A` and `C`.

[image]

Like this:

[image] -->
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub demo()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ' expand all groups on sheet
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
        ' remove any existing groups
        .Rows.Ungroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set r = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With r
        'identify common groups in column B
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum B changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it!!! There is a trifle somewhere, because it stops working, when it find only one same line, eg. `text1 text1 text1` **`text2`** `text3 text3`.

Comment: @gaffcz I solved that bug in a slightly different way: see updated code