# Group Rows by Formula Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Very similar question to this one -> [Group rows by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824529/group-rows-by-value)

The only difference is the values I'm grouping are formulas. See below for example data (can't seem to embed images correctly)

Sample data

[image]

Desired output

[image]

The code below modified below from answer linked to above.

```
Sub demo()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ' expand all groups on sheet
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
        ' remove any existing groups
        .Rows.Ungroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set r = .Range("D6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With r
        'identify common groups in column D
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Formula
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum D changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wether or not the value in a cell is the result of a formula or a constant is irrelevant.   Using the linked answer code as is should work for you

Comment: @chrisneilsen I thought so too, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Then post about _that_. (What you expect, what you get, any error msg's and the line throwing it, sample data _as text_ , MSVE, etc)

Comment: Just noticed `Set r = .Range("D6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))`  that's doing End(xlUp) on column B, which is empty.  Change the 2 to 4 (col D)