# Group rows by value over more than one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

ive been looking into adding a groupBy function on a couple of sheets however i want to reference 5 sheets. In total i have about 7 but two of the worksheets have the common values in different columns (the five sheets have common variables in column B however two have the same variables in column G) otherwise i would have used ActiveSheet.

I've attached Chris Neilsen's example

[Chris Neilsen's Group By Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824529/group-rows-by-value)

```
Sub demo()
Dim r As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

With ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    ' expand all groups on sheet
    .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
    ' remove any existing groups
    .Rows.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set r = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

With r
    'identify common groups in column B
    j = 1
    v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
        If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
            ' Colum B changed, create group
            v = .Cells(i, 1)
            If i > j + 1 Then
                .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
            End If
            j = i
            v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    ' create last group
    If i > j + 1 Then
        .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
    End If
    ' collapse all groups
    .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried the below code to link the sheets in the above example however it is out of range

```
With Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by adding a parameter to the sub code from Chris Neilsen:

```vb
Sub demo(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        ' expand all groups on sheet
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
        ' remove any existing groups
        .Rows.Ungroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set r = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With r
        'identify common groups in column B
        j = 1
        v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If v <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
                ' Colum B changed, create group
                v = .Cells(i, 1)
                If i > j + 1 Then
                    .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
                End If
                j = i
                v = .Cells(j, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        ' create last group
        If i > j + 1 Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
        End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

Now call that routine with any worksheet, or in a loop:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        demo ws
    Next ws
End Sub
```

PS: I do suggest changing the name of `demo` to something more appropriate, such as `GroupDataOnSheet`.